# Haskell Data.Set has `unions`, but not `intersections`? Why?

Tags: haskell

I need to take the `intersection` of a list of Sets, and noticed that there is an function

```
unions :: Ord a => [Set a] -> Set a
    The union of a list of sets: (unions == foldl union empty).
```

but no corresponding function `intersections`.  Is there a good reason for this, or is this just an oversight?

Don't get me wrong, it is super easy to define this as

```
intersections = foldl1 intersection
```

but I just find it curious that one is there, and the other not.

Comment: I guess it's because `intersections` won't be a total function. Consider `union` and `intersection` as monoids on set of sets, identity for `union` is just `empty` but identity for `intersection` is not well defined.

Comment: To address the totality concerns, I could imagine having an `intersectionsMay` function that returns `Maybe`.

Comment: @zakyggaps The unit for `intersection` is not well-defined _for this particular representation of sets_. You could instead represent sets intensionally `type Set a = a -> Bool`, then `intersection s t = \x -> s x && t x` and the unit of intersection is the set containing everything, `universe = const True`

Comment: There's no totality problem: `intersections sets = case sets of; [] -> empty; _ -> foldl1' intersection sets`

Comment: @JeffClites Not if you expect properties like `intersections (x:xs) == intersection x (intersections xs)` to hold. Each `intersection` can only take away elements, never add new ones. Each time you add one more set to the list of sets you're intersecting the size of the results must shrink (or at most stay the same), so each time you *remove* a set from the list of sets you're intersecting the size of the result must grow (or stay the same). Take away all of the sets and the resulting set should grow to the most inclusive set possible, not shrink to empty.

Comment: @Ben I don't think of those properties as being definitional of what an intersection is. To me, the intersection of some sets is the set of items in all of those sets. That works for two sets, more than two sets, one set, or zero sets (if there are no sets there are no items).

Comment: @JeffClites Note that `all (elem 8) ([] :: [Set Integer])` returns `True`; every set in the empty list of sets contains `8` (because there are no counter-examples that *don't* contain `8`). So `8` should logically be in the `intersections` of that list of sets, by your plain language definition. Same goes for anything other element. It really comes down to the exact same logic whereby an empty conjuction is `True` (which is in fact what `all _ []` is doing). You certainly *could* define `intersections [] = empty` just to have a computable value, but it will have surprising corner cases.